# DSP processor: some beginner's questions

Tags: fft, self-study

I have started making a project involving FFT to some accoustic signal(so far I completed some theory), with a DSP processor, and according to some calculations, make the output going to a bluetooth (or any other wireless device) chip, which will transmit to a bluetooth receiver.

So far I have seen wireless chips, and DSP proccessors, but not from the same company.

- Programming each chip that came from a different company requires different softwares or big differences in commands?
- Is there a company making both DSPs and bluetooth?
- If you have some tips regarding the chips I will be happy to read them :) (easiest way to begin, where I should go into the architecture and what is less importent and can look at it from a bigger picture)

Comment: What amount of processing power (MACs, Mflops, etc.) do you need, and what amount of Bluetooth bandwidth (low enough for BLE)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v have some experience with TI C55 and C6000 series DSPs, I'll give you some points, hope to be helpful.

> Programming each chip that came from a different company requires different softwares or big differences in commands?

Absolutely! Although the code body might be the same, but since every company has its special processor architecture, their compilers would be different. Even two DSPs of a same company might be too different, for example Texas Instruments C5000 processors are too different from C6000, since their memory architecture is different. I mean, you can't simply use the same segment of code for both.

> Is there a company making both DSPs and Bluetooth?

Usually most of the DSPs are only Microprocessor and a few essential Interfacing (like I2C, SPI,...) are considered for them, however some are more sophisticated System on a Chip designs might include Bluetooth. Basically you can buy and add a Bluetooth module to any DSP you want.
https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12574

> If you have some tips regarding the chips I will be happy to read them :) (easiest way to begin, where I should go into the architecture and what is less importent and can look at it from a bigger picture)

It depends on your programming level and those calculations you've mentioned above, however, I think the best chip to begin with is MicroChip DSPIC, which is simply a PIC micro associated with some DSP blocks (like circular conv, FFT ,etc), I think your last choice should be TI's DSPs or AD's Shark DSPs, they are too complicated and frustrating to begin with.

Comment: Thank You.
i noticed sparkfun products cost more than their counterparts(for example http://www.atmel.com/devices/ATBTLC1000.aspx)
is there any big reason for it?(the end goal is to buy several of these chips, so the price is important)

Comment: You are right, Atmel's are way too cheaper, By that link I meant Bluetooth modules in general. The only thing you must really take care when you buy your module is its "Host Interface", make sure it is compatible with your micros interfacing.